# Unusual problem regarding old water damage, new battery not charging macbook air mid 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, damage

I have quite strange problem. I had some water damage on my computer few month ago. After it dried completely computer worked only when I unplugged the battery but if I unplugged the charger my computer was resetting itself (date and time were resetting, it took much longer to load)meaning that it had to be always charged in order to work. So I decided to buy new battery. After I inserted it the magsafe charger didnt work but the battery did (it was on the 50%). I tried also with two other chargers with no success. So computer was working just until my battery didn't drained completely. I did SMC reset wich didn't help. After I unplugged the battery computer worked again. What do you think is causing the problem? Can I do something to repair it? Is it wise to buy another new battery? Could it be a problem with a magsafe board or with a logic board? Can I replace these parts by myself and what are the costs?

Thank you for your help,

Greets

Answer (score 1):

I'm summarizing your points, for my own reference and in case I misunderstood a point. Please point out any errors in my interpretation.

- Water damage, computer only works when unplugged battery
- But unplug charger, computer resets date and time, longer load
- Thus, always needed 100% charge
- Bought a new battery
- But with this, the charger no longer works, battery does
- Tried two other chargers, no joy
- And with the battery, could use computer until battery drained completely

Okay, with that summarized, I would suggest that there were two-or-more connectors (i.e., problems) that developed oxide as a result of the water damage.

One problem was related to the original battery, which you disconnected.

Second problem was revealed when installing a new battery, which revealed there was still an issue that was not specifically the battery. And you've confirmed that this issue isn't caused by the charger.

For your reference, here's a [Teardown of Apple's Magsafe connector](http://www.righto.com/2013/06/teardown-and-exploration-of-magsafe.html), in case of use to you.

I can see that you like to work with electronics, so I won't discourage you from doing repairs because you know the risks. However, if you ultimately send the unit in for repairs, then know that the technician will recognize the unit as a problem because "someone" had a go at repairs (i.e., potential problems introduced).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for fast and good response. You got it right. At least the most of it. So my computer didn't change his behaviour with a new battery. Once the new battery drained completely I could not use my computer with plugged in battery so it worked only unplugged as before with old one. So I am guessing that the old battery is still working but it is just a guess. 

So now I am sending the new battery back to get my money back..will buy new magsafe board to test if it works with old battery. If not, I will buy new battery again and test it again. 

I will post the end result.
Thank you!